# find minimum and maximum value in attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, max, min

I need to find minimum and maximum value in data attribute but it returns 0

here is my code

```
<div data-price="2" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="5" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="3" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="0" class="maindiv">test</div> 
<div data-price="25" class="maindiv">test</div>     
<div data-price="10" class="maindiv">test</div> 

<script>
    var ids = $("div[data-price]").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    var highest = Math.max.apply( Math, ids );
    var lowest = Math.min.apply( Math, ids );

    alert(highest);
    alert(lowest);
</script>
```

Comment: Did these answers provide solution to your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return **data-price** attribute, not its id

```js
var ids = $("div[data-price]").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-price");
}).get();

var highest = Math.max.apply( Math, ids );
var lowest = Math.min.apply( Math, ids );

alert(highest);
alert(lowest);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-price="2" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="5" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="3" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="0" class="maindiv">test</div> 
<div data-price="25"class="maindiv">test</div>     
<div data-price="10" class="maindiv">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular JavaScript:

```js
//Variable to hold our results
var data = [];
//Loop through HTML nodes
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".maindiv").length; i++) {
 data.push({
  node : document.querySelectorAll(".maindiv")[i],
  value : parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".maindiv")[i].getAttribute("data-price"))
 });
}
//Sort lowest to highest (Only use one sort! Pick either this or the next one as they overwrite each Other)
data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
 });
//Sort highest to lowest (Only use one sort! Pick either this or the last one as they overwrite each Other)
data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.value - a.value;
 });
//List all
console.log(data);
//List first (highest or lowest depending or sort)
console.log('first', data[0].value);
//List last (highest or lowest depending or sort)
console.log('last', data[data.length-1].value);
```

```html
<div data-price="2" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="5" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="3" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-price="0" class="maindiv">test</div> 
<div data-price="25" class="maindiv">test</div>     
<div data-price="10" class="maindiv">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are returning the id attribute from the `map` function. Change it to to `data-price`

```
var ids = $("div[data-price]").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("price");
}).get();
var highest = Math.max.apply( Math, ids );
var lowest = Math.min.apply( Math, ids );
alert(highest)
alert(lowest)
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5845/)